# What's a noun for the group of people who you're very close to, such as family, friends, relatives, and significant others?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

If I wanted to describe all of the people close to someone such as their close friends, family, relatives, and spouse/significant other, how would I do so with one noun?

The simplest 'noun' that comes to mind is using the term "friends and family", e.g. "He sought consolation from his friends and family during the tragic incident."

Is there a more specific/powerful noun for this? An example of a [loanword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) for this would be the Hawaiian *Ohana*.

I might be missing something obvious here, but I'd like to know what you guys think. I'm not looking for a specific answer, and loanwords would be great as well - possibly better!

edit: I don't care if it's a single word, actually.

Comment: Maybe clumsy isn't the best word to describe it. Perhaps it's a personal thing, but *friends and family* can sound a little inauthentic/trite.  *Ohana* is a good one, but I did mention that in the question. I'm looking for more examples.

Comment: @medica Haha yes, we seem to think very alike. I removed the single word request tag a couple of minutes ago. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call all of them as ***family***. Because you can also call your friends that is very close to you with kinship terms like "brother","sister" etc. It is not a true kinship but it is called fictive kinship.

Also, ***[kinfolk](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kinfolk&page=4)*** (and *folks*) is used in this sense:

> The people you hold the closest in life, or are related to.

---

As a phrase, there is ***[kith and kin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kin)***:

> friends and relatives; people known to someone.

Also, ***[kith](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kith)*** itself means everyone you know but usually used in the above phrase.

> familiar friends, neighbors, or relatives

<sup>Sources: Urban Dictionary, The Free Dictionary, and Merriam-Webster</sup>

Answer (score 4):

loved ones

nearest and dearest

Answer (score 3):

I think that another common  expression to indicate the group of people with which you have your main contacts  in life is [your circle](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/circle) namely,  *family circle and circle of friends*

Answer (score 2):

A slang Australian expression is "My mob". But that consists of two words.